# 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method TabHighlightDisplay when compiling assets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm getting a weird, class issue with some of my assets files.
It works fine on 2 macs, but on my macbook it errors with "A definition for this class could not be found in the class path"

I'm pretty sure something is going wrong flash, it has it's paths wrong or weirdness is happening, the base class for the symbol exists and like I said works fine on other machines.

When I check the symbol properties for the asset that's causing issues, I enter the base class correctly, the Check class button says that the class has been found (TabHighlight.as)

[image: AS Export base class found]

But when I click OK on the same symbol properties dialog another alert pops up that says actually, the class can't be found so one will be created during export.
Waaaa?

[image: AS Export "OK" class missing]

There's clearly something wrong, but the class is there and i have definitely correctly set the source paths it works for my other computer and my colleagues as well. Just my laptop!

I've been banging my head over this for a good few hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first dialog confirms the presence of class `TabHighlite`, the second one warns, that there isn't class `TabHighliteDisplay` in your class paths. If there were class `TabHighliteDisplay` flash would use it, but by default Flash generates stub for it. It sounds like you check the box "Don't show again" in your 2 Mac and just forgot about this )

Comment: I think you're right I actually dont need to care about this warning. thanks for your time.